# How to use a COI and a person's name in the same sentence

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

If I want to say
"I asked him as well as Sam"
Or
"He told me to speak to you and Jeff"

Would it be: 
"Je le lui ai demandé ainsi qu'à Sam
"Il m'a dit de vous parler et à Jeff"

It wouldn't be correct to say "...demandé à lui et Sam" for example, would it?

Answer (score 2):

*Je le lui ai demandé, ainsi qu'à Sam* est correct. Une virgule avant *ainsi* est souhaitable.

*Il m'a dit de vous parler et à Jeff* : Il manque quelques trucs pour la rendre sensée :

- Soit *Il m'a dit de vous parler et à Jeff **aussi***
- Soit, mieux : *Il m'a dit de vous parler, **à vous** et (à) Jeff*

Answer (score 2):

Your first translation :
   `Je le lui ai demandé ainsi qu'à Sam` 
is correct, and you are right to say that

`Je le lui ai demandé à lui et Sam` is incorrect.

But you might have said:

`Je le leur ai demandé, à Sam et lui`

Here, it's better to put Sam first, because when you enumerate people, it is recommended to order them from the farthest to the nearest: `Paul, toi et moi` and here, "lui" is supposed to be part of the context, so he is nearer than "Sam" who can just appear.

But you can't say:

```
Il m'a dit de vous parler et à Jeff
```

Here, you have to separate the complement by repeating vous:

```
Il m'a dit de vous parler, à vous et à Jeff
```

or `à Jeff et vous`